# How to decode JSON in Perl language?

Tags: json, perl

How to decode JSON in Perl language?

My try:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
$web_source = get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json');
$decoded_json = decode_json($web_source);
print $decoded_json;
```

Error:

> Undefined subroutine &main::decode_json called at api.pl line 4.

How to correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use JSON;
```

I hope you know that the URL you are trying to access wants authorization though.

Answer (score 4):

You can decode json like this in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use JSON;
    use Data::Dumper;

    $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

    $text = decode_json($json);
    print  Dumper($text);
```